# Is there an easy way to deploy my users cloud functions and execute them?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a saas product.
In the product, users can create workflows.

I would like to give them the ability to add js functions to the workflow, in order to process the data at given steps. Something limited (http call, basic data structure manipulation and condition, for, etc). The same as Cloud functions or lambda but even simpler.

Is there a way to do that easily ? Maybe by using Google Cloud functions, create one dynamically and remove it after execution ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest?

Comment: What is blocking you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Didn't see that.

"Manages lightweight user-provided functions executed in response to events." seems to match my use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [REST API to manage Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest) that allows you to deploy functions however you see fit. I imagine that's what most similar VAR solutions use.